# Transform AmazonS3 send to RX android observable

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3, rx-java, rx-android

How would I transform this async call to use RX Android and have the ability
to chain it to other calls?
Currently I use EventBus to inform that sending succeeded or failed, but I would like to use RX, mostly for chaining purposes.

```
public void SendToAmazon(Intent i) {
    try {
        // take params from intent
        // .......................

        // Create an S3 client
        s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID, MY_SECRET_KEY));
        // Set the region of your S3 bucket
        s3Client.setRegion(com.amazonaws.regions.Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1));

        String newFilename = fileName+"/img.jpg";
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(
                AmazonS3FetchParams.MY_BUCKET_NAME, newFilename, new java.io.File( fileURI) )
                .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)
                .withStorageClass(StorageClass.Standard);
        try {
            putObjectRequest.setGeneralProgressListener(new S3ProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPersistableTransfer(PersistableTransfer persistableTransfer) {

                }

                @Override
                public void progressChanged(com.amazonaws.event.ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
                    if (progressEvent.getEventCode() == ProgressEvent.COMPLETED_EVENT_CODE) {
                        Log.d("Info", "TRANSFER finished: " + progressEvent.getBytesTransferred() + " bytes");
                        SentToS3Event sentEvent = new SentToS3Event(fileName, fileURI, position,
                                0, from, nrRetry, messageDbId, getAmazonImageUrl(fileName));
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(sentEvent);
                    } else if (progressEvent.getEventCode() == ProgressEvent.FAILED_EVENT_CODE) {
                        SentToS3Event sentEvent = new SentToS3Event(fileName, fileURI, position,
                                -1, from, nrRetry, messageDbId, getAmazonImageUrl(fileName));
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(sentEvent);
                    }
                }
            });

            PutObjectResult objectResult = s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
            error = 0;
        } catch (AmazonClientException aex) {
            Log.e("Info", "AMAZON EXCEPTION ! " + aex.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = -1;
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this piece of code. I managed to make it work in another situation.

```
    final PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest("a", "b", "c");
    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<SomeAmazonModel>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super SomeAmazonModel> subscriber) {
            putObjectRequest.setGeneralProgressListener(new S3ProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPersistableTransfer(PersistableTransfer persistableTransfer) {

                }

                @Override
                public void progressChanged(com.amazonaws.event.ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
                    if (progressEvent.getEventCode() == ProgressEvent.COMPLETED_EVENT_CODE) {
                        subscriber.onNext(new SomeAmazonModel(ProgressEvent.COMPLETED_EVENT_CODE));
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    } else if (progressEvent.getEventCode() == ProgressEvent.FAILED_EVENT_CODE) {
                        subscriber.onNext(new SomeAmazonModel(ProgressEvent.COMPLETED_EVENT_CODE));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).subscribe(new Action1<SomeAmazonModel>() {
        @Override
        public void call(SomeAmazonModel someAmazonModel) {
            // Subscribe to above Observable and handle result
            someAmazonModel.getEventCode();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This works, but can you add one more detail of how to chain next calls in RX manner ?

Comment: Can you explain it a bit "chain next calls" ? Do you want to execute another call after first one succeed ? Or execute call each time something happend e.g. "press button". Or maybe execute multiple calls one by one ?

Comment: Sorry, kinda starting my way using RX, so my terminology may not be the correct. So, what I need is, after async execution of  S3 send, I need to execute more RX calls. Please take a look at:
https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android#chaining-tasks-together
That is something I am trying to accomplish with RX.

Comment: This may fit your needs: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html

Observable<SomeAmazonModel> someModel = Observable.create(...).concatWith(Observable.create(...)).concatWith

Remember that second Observable will be executed only if first Observable emited onCompleted

Comment: I suppose .concatWith combined with .flatMap in each observable should do the job.